# MongoDB Driver C# : Equivalent "Contains" in nested object?

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I've this class/collection

```
public class Post
{
    private Person Author {get; set;}
}

public class Person 
{
    private string Lastname {get; set;}
    private string Firstname {get; set;}
}
```

I would like search all authors with a firstname which contains "jean" like : jean, jean-michel, jean-pierre...

How I can do this with MongoDB Driver in C# ?

I try

```
var list = myPostCollection.Find(d => d.Author.Firstname.Contains("Jean")).ToList();
```

Result : InvalidOperationException: {document}{Author}.Firstname is not supported.

```
var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.Regex("Author.Firstname", new BsonRegularExpression("Jean"));
var list = myPostCollection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

None error, but I have no result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be able to use the following code to achieve matching within a string.

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();
var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
var posts = db.GetCollection<Post>("posts");

await posts.InsertManyAsync(new[]
{
    new Post {Author = new Person {Firstname = "jean-michel", Lastname = "l2"}},
    new Post {Author = new Person {Firstname = "jean-pierre", Lastname = "l2"}},
    new Post {Author = new Person {Firstname = "bob-pierre", Lastname = "l2"}}
});

var filter =
    Builders<Post>.Filter.Regex(x => x.Author.Firstname, new Regex("jean", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));

var results = await posts.Find(filter)
    .ToListAsync();

foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"FirstName: {result.Author.Firstname}");
}

// FirstName: jean-michel
// FirstName: jean-pierre
```